# Select a portion of data in MySQL from offset to offset

Tags: mysql

Quick question about MySQL. I have a table with about 7000+ entries and I would like to select for example from OFFSET 40 until OFFSET 60. So it would bring back 20 entries. I'm pretty new to SQL and know of the OFFSET command, just not sure how to do this.

Thanks,
Kris

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: [RTFM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html#id896545) - the manual is your friend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `LIMIT`. Its arguments are an offset and a limit on the number of posts to retrieve--in your case, the following:

```
SELECT * FROM entries LIMIT 40, 20
```